# How Use PublicApp.Config In All Of My Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I Have One solution And 4 Project.

in all project i have a APP.Config File.

And i can use that on the same project.

i have one Solution Folder that contain this file PublicApp.Config

i want use this configuration in all my project (4 project.)

i `add existing file` file this file in all 4 project `Add as link`

but i can not access to a `<appSettings>`

i want one of my project have one class that map all public confiquration in to one propertie.

my solution like this :

i have this solution folder `Configurations` and i have this file name inside that `PublicAPP.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ComputerName" value="Ardalan-Pc"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

i have this file `GetConfiguration.cs` inside another project for map configuration in propetrie.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{

public static class GetConfiguration
{

    public static string ComputerName
    {
        get
        {

            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ComputerName"];
        }
    }

}

}
```

and now i do not know how i can get AppSettings["ComputerName"] from my PublicAPP.Config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized that I can do the following.

Instead of a Solution folder I can use one project with one App.Config that contain all my public configuration .

And i Think This Project Most Be Start Up Project In My Solution.because System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager can get only attribute from app.config of start up project

and i create down class inside this project.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{

public static class GetConfiguration
{

public static string ComputerName
{
    get
    {

        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ComputerName"];
    }
}

}

}
```

and then i reference in project in all other project and use this static class.

Of course, if someone has a better way please give me the information.